# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'

Tags: python, typeerror

```
import requests
import selectorlib

URL = "http://programmer100.pythonanywhere.com/tours/"

def scrape(url):
    response = requests.get(url, HEADERS)
    source = response.text
    return source


def extract(source):
    extractor = selectorlib.Extractor.from_yaml_file("extract.yaml")
    value = extractor.extract(source)["tours"]
    return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraped = scrape(URL)
    extracted = extract(scraped)
    print(extracted)
```

This code is showing the TypeError.

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'NoneType'Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python course\scraping-music-band\main.py", line 24, in 
extracted = extract(scraped)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Python course\scraping-music-band\main.py", line 18, in extract
value = extractor.extract(source)["tours"]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 2):

This error indicating that a function received a None value when it was expecting to receive a string.  In your code, this error is likely occurring because the extractor.extract(source) call is returning None, and you’re trying to access the "tours" key of None.
Can try this lines to handle the error

```
def extract(source):
    extractor = selectorlib.Extractor.from_yaml_file("extract.yaml")
    data = extractor.extract(source)
    if data is None:
        print("No data could be extracted from the source.")
        return None
    value = data.get("tours")
    if value is None:
        print("No 'tours' could be found in the extracted data.")
        return None
    return value
```

With this code the function checks if data and value are None before trying to access any keys, and prints a message to help with debugging. You might want to adjust the error messages to better suit your needs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: still got the same error